# c# Create text file with spaces between lines

Tags: c#, text-files

I would like to create new text file with spaces. for example:

> a
>
> b
>
> c

This is my code, and I find for other simple way to create it (because I have lots of lines):

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
writer.Write("a" + Environment.NewLine + "b" + Environment.NewLine + "c");
writer.Close();
```

Comment: `i have lots of lines` Where are you getting the data for all those lines?

Comment: Look up the `using` statement.  You should use it with anything that implements IDisposable, such as StreamWriter and FileStream.  Currently if an exception is thrown in your code, the file will not be closed.

Comment: Im not getting data, i write the data. if its important for you, so i write an RDP file.

Comment: What are you going to write into the file?  Where are "lots of lines" coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your lines in a `lines` variable (it could be a string array or any `IEnumerable<string>` etc.), you can use `string.Join` to concatenate all of your lines with a newline between them and then write:

```
using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1))
{
    writer.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
}
```

Also, you should always dispose of any object that implements `IDisposable`, and the `using` statement in the above example is an easy and neat way to do it.

You can also use `File.WriteAllText` for a simple case like this to avoid writing all that boilerplate code:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myfile.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    foreach (string line in yourlines)
    {
       writer.Write(line + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    writer.Close();
```

Comment: WriteText is completely unnecessary, and IDisposable are not addressed

Comment: Who said IDisposable needed to be addressed? I don't think his question mentioned the proper way to handle file streams!!!!!!!